# Create Sign-in-with-Google button in Flutter in accordance with the terms

Tags: android, button, authentication, dart, flutter

I'd like to add a "Sign in with Google" Button to my Flutter app. This button should be in accordance with the [terms](https://developers.google.com/identity/branding-guidelines) of Google.

My problem is, that the button I've create looks really awful.

I used the images which Google provides on their website but I don't know if I'm doing right with the code for the button.

```
  Widget _createLoginButtonGoogle() {
    return new Expanded(
      child: new Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30.0, 5.0, 30.0, 5.0),
        child: new RaisedButton(
          color: const Color(0xFF4285F4),
          shape: _createButtonBorder(),
          onPressed: () {},
          child: new Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              new Image.asset(
                'res/images/icons/google/btn_google_dark_normal_mdpi.9.png',
                height: 48.0,
              ),
              new Expanded(
                child: _createButtonText('Sign in with Google', Colors.white),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

What I want is that my button looks like the original Google button

[image: original google button]

And not like my version

[image: my version of the google button]

Can anyone tell me how to create the original google button? Is there a better way than creating a `RaisedButton`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm giving you a general idea, replace Android icon with your Google image using `Image.asset(google_image)`

```dart
InkWell(
  onTap: () {},
  child: Ink(
    color: Color(0xFF397AF3),
    child: Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(6),
      child: Wrap(
        crossAxisAlignment: WrapCrossAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Icon(Icons.android), // <-- Use 'Image.asset(...)' here
          SizedBox(width: 12),
          Text('Sign in with Google'),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 18):

There Is A Pretty Awesome Package Called [flutter_signin_button](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_signin_button) on [pub.dev](https://pub.dev).

You Can Use It It Has Sign In Buttons For

- Email
- Google
- Facebook
- GitHub
- LinkedIn
- Pinterest
- Tumblr
- Twitter
- Apple

With Some Supporting Dark Mode Also With Mini Buttons!

First Add It To Your `pubspec.yaml`

```yaml
dependencies:
  ...
  flutter_signin_button:
```

then import it into your file:

```
import 'package:flutter_signin_button/flutter_signin_button.dart';
```

and use the buttons like this:

```
SignInButton(
  Buttons.Google,
  onPressed: () {},
)
```

Here Is A Preview Of All The Buttons:
[image]

Comment: not sure why this still isn't the accepted answer despite having more upvotes than the current accepted one.

Comment: is there a way to resize them?

Comment: @HammadNasir yes, they will adapt the size of the parent.

Comment: @BartekPacia the reason it isn't updated is because it doesn't need to be updated. it is just some ui components so they don't need frequent updates like packages riverpod or getx.

Answer (score 3):

```dart
 ElevatedButton(
                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                  primary: Colors.white,
                  onPrimary: Colors.black,
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  googleLogin();
                },
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 8, 0, 8),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: const [
                      Image(
                        image: AssetImage("assets/google_logo.png"),
                        height: 18.0,
                        width: 24,
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 24, right: 8),
                        child: Text(
                          'Sign in with Google',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 20,
                            color: Colors.black54,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

for more you can change the Text font to Roboto Medium and make the size 14x, based on the branding rule https://developers.google.com/identity/branding-guidelines#font

[image: Sign with google]

Answer (score 1):

you can use Padding property of raised button also use property of Row widget and mainAxisSize of button. Following code may help you to understand clearly.

```
 new Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30.0, 5.0, 30.0, 5.0),
      child: new RaisedButton(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 3.0,bottom: 3.0,left: 3.0),
        color: const Color(0xFF4285F4),
        onPressed: () {},
        child: new Row(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            new Image.asset(
              'res/images/icons/google/btn_google_dark_normal_mdpi.9.png',
              height: 48.0,
            ),
            new Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0,right: 10.0),
                child: new Text("Sign in with Google",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),)
            ),
          ],
        )
      ),
    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

use this one

```
      child: InkWell(
        onTap: () {},
        child: Container(
          height: 50,
          width: CustomWidth(context) - 100,
          color: Colors.blueAccent,
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 3),
                height: 45,
                width: 50,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    image: DecorationImage(
                        image: NetworkImage("https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/2991/2991148.png"))),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                width: 10,
              ),
              DefaultTextView(
                text: "SignUp With Google",
                color: AppColors.whiteColor,
                fontweight: FontWeight.bold,
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Answer (score -1):

For google logo image on white background and raised button with blue background:

```
Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30.0, 5.0, 30.0, 5.0),
          child: new RaisedButton(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
              color: const Color(0xff4285F4),
              onPressed: () async {
                _signInWithGoogle();
              },
              child: new Row(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    child: Image.asset(
                      Images.googleLogo,
                      height: 18.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10.0),
                      child: new Text(
                        "Sign in with Google",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      )),
                ],
              )),
        ),
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use this class and just need to pass function and add google icon in your assets/images folder and change the icon name in code, and you are good to go.

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:social_app/constants/colors.dart';
    
    class GoogleSignInButton extends StatefulWidget {
      final function;
      final String buttonText;
    
      const GoogleSignInButton(
          {super.key, required this.function, required this.buttonText});
    
      @override
      State<StatefulWidget> createState() => GoogleSignInButtonState();
    }
    
    class GoogleSignInButtonState extends State<GoogleSignInButton> {
      bool isButtonClicked = false;
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Container(
          height: 50,
          width: double.infinity,
          child: ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: isButtonClicked
                ? () {}
                : () async {
                    setState(() {
                      isButtonClicked = true;
                    });
                    await widget.function();
                    setState(() {
                      isButtonClicked = false;
                    });
                  },
            style: ButtonStyle(
              padding: MaterialStateProperty.all<EdgeInsets>(EdgeInsets.zero),
              shape: isButtonClicked
                  ? MaterialStateProperty.all<CircleBorder>(CircleBorder())
                  : MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                      RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                    )),
              backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(mainColor),
            ),
            child: isButtonClicked
                ? Container(
                    height: 25,
                    width: 25,
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  )
                : Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(3)),
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                          child: Image.asset("assets/images/google_icon.png"),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          width: 30,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          "Sign in with google",
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: Adding a preview is always recommended.